# Get instance of nodes by their name in SimpleXML (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml, instance, nodes

I'd like to search for nodes with the same node name in a SimpleXML Object no matter how deep they are nested and create an instance of them as an array.

In the HTML DOM I can do that with JavaScript by using `getElementsByTagName()`. Is there a way to do that in PHP as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes use xpath

$xml->xpath('//div');

Here $xml is your SimpleXML object.

In this example you will get array of all 'div' elements

Comment: Thanks! I tried it before, but (why the hell ever) it did not work. Now I tried again and it works. Maybe a cache problem. :S

Comment: You probably used only 1 forward slash? You need to use 2 // to find ALL elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $fname = dirname(__FILE__) . '\\xml\\crRoll.xml';  
  $dom = new DOMDocument; 
  $dom->load($fname, LIBXML_DTDLOAD|LIBXML_DTDATTR);
  $root = $dom->documentElement;                     

  $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);  
  $xpath->registerNamespace('cr', "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"); 
  $candidateNodes = $xpath->query("//cr:break");  

  foreach ($candidateNodes as $child) {
    $max = $child->getAttribute('tstamp');
  }
```

This finds all the BREAK nodes (tstamp attr) using XPath ...

Answer (score 0):

Only on [DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php),
however, you can [import/export SimpleXML into DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php),
or simply use DOMDocument to parse XML.

Another answer mentioned about Xpath,
it will return duplication of node, if you have something like :-

```
<div><div>1</div></div>
```